# Creating tables on registration in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The question is not new in any way but it has a small twist to it.
My webpage is a membership page where users places bets. My idea is to create a new table for the users(with a naming convention like **TABLE userBet+$userid**) bets. User login information is already handled, my goal is now to save the bets of the user to a new table. A table which is created when users register. This will hopefully make score counting easier. Am I right or wrong? Could this be done in a better way?  (Everything is done in PHP MySQL)

User registers -> Table for bets get created

> "CREATE Table $userID ,id_bet, games, result, points"

And then matching this table against the correct result?

So again my questions: Is this a good way to do it? Is creating a table with the userID a smart thing to do?

**EDIT**

The bets is always 40 matches, which makes the tables Huge with columns and rows.
Should I make 40 Tables, one for each games instead? and put all users in there?

Comment: Altering the schema on user input is highly not recommended. Just have user_bets table with user_id column

Comment: If I have a user_bets table for every bet, then i will have a hard time counting score? or if it is the best way, then i would need to do it that way :) ?

Comment: What score you have to count? Total points?:) `SELECT SUM(points) FROM user_bets WHERE user_id = $userID`. This will give you the sum of the points on given userID. If you have separate table, you will have `SELECT SUM(points) FROM $userID` which is exactly the same, but querying different tables. Querying different tables will give you hard time to cache the results if you want to use query cache, also you will end up with like 10 000 tables in your db, if you have 10 000 users. Your db will get heavy.

Comment: well I guess your right on that one, the problem is that I want to save around 40 matches/player, should I create a Table for each match then and put all users in that, or one table called user_bets with all 40 matches/player, there will be 40 columns and 1000 rows :) ?

Comment: @Rocksteady I've seen tables perform ok with over 1mil rows - 1000 will be fine!

Comment: What matches/player are? Can't you have only match_id's and relate them with player_id's in user_bets table

Comment: @Rocksteady Why 40 columns though? Are you creating columns for each match?

Comment: Well I was thinking that every match should have a column? or hove should everything be stored in user_bet table otherwise? Match_id and then have a table that links the match_id to a match "England-Brazil"?

Comment: yes, you have `matches` table with i.e. `id, name` => `1, England-Brazi`, so in `user_bets` you have `id, user_id, match_id, games, points, result`, and if you want to link the user points for the match - England-Brazil, you will put under match_id the value of `1`

Comment: Ok so i guess `id, user_id, match_id, points, result`, "games" won't be necessary then. This sound great! post as answer will you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer due to author's request : )

Suggested database schema:

table `matches`:

```
id |   name   |
---------------
 1 |   A vs B |
```

table `user_bets`

```
id | user_id | match_id | points | result |
-------------------------------------------
 1 |    X    |    1     |    Y   |   Z    |
```

Where match_id is related on `matches`.`id`

user_id = user.id

user_bets is only one table, containing all the info. No need of separate tables, as it was clear from the comments it's considered bad practice to alter the db schema via user input.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right or wrong?

You are wrong. Dynamically altering your database schema will only make it **harder** to work with. There's no advantage you gain from doing so. You can do the same things by storing all bets within the same table, adding a column `userid`.